# CGLib: cannot find override method

Tags: java, exception, cglib

I have code:

```
 1  abstract class A {
 2    public abstract <T> T getId();
 3  }
 4  class B extend A {
 5    public Long getId() {
 6      return Long.valueOf(1);
 7     }
 8  }
 9  public class Main {
10    public static void main(String [] args) {
11      FastClass fast = FastClass.create(B.class);
12      FastMethod fastMethod = fast.getMethod("getId", null);
13      try {
14        final B b = new B();
15        Long value = (Long) fastMethod.invoke(b, null);
16      } catch (Exception e) {//
17        e.printStackTrace();
18      }
19    }
20  }
```

and on line 12 throws **IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find method public java.lang.Long B.getId()**.

How I can get instance FastMethod class and execute FastMethod.invoke()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must obtain instance **FastClass** for class **A** and obtain instance **FastMethod** from it, but invoke instance **FastMethod** with parameter instance class **B**.

This code work fine:

```
 1  abstract class A {
 2    public abstract <T> T getId();
 3  }
 4  class B extend A {
 5    public Long getId() {
 6      return Long.valueOf(1);
 7     }
 8  }
 9  public class Main {
10    public static void main(String [] args) {
11      FastClass fast = FastClass.create(A.class); // changed, was FastClass.create(B.class)
12      FastMethod fastMethod = fast.getMethod("getId", null);
13      try {
14        final B b = new B();
15        Long value = (Long) fastMethod.invoke(b, null);
16      } catch (Exception e) {
17        e.printStackTrace();
18      }
19    }
20  }
```